# Legendre Symbol of a Very, Very Large Value

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

I'm trying to use [FLINT (Fast Library for Number Theory)](https://github.com/wbhart/flint2) to calculate the Legendre Symbol of the following:

$$\left(\frac{n! + 1}{p}\right)$$

In my case, $p$ is a positive, odd prime (specifically $1,000,000,000,039 $), so I should be able to use the Jacobi symbol in its place when attempting to compute it.

How do I simplify the *numerator* if $n$ is a very large number, specifically $208,463,325,489$?

My current thought is that I would need to calculate `n! mod p` (which I believe is just a running product modulo `p`) and then add `1` before computing the symbol.

The value of `n! mod p` that I computed using FLINT is $133,008,788,325$, but I'm not sure if that's the correct value that I should be using in place of `n!` when computing the symbol.

Is it possible to simplify this mathematically so that I can verify that my computation is correct?

Comment: So the question is actually about computing factorials modulo a prime, not Legendre symbols specifically

Comment: @Wojowu That depends if computing a factorial modulo a prime is the correct method to use when computing the Legendre symbol, which is what I'm confused about. I'm having a lot of trouble finding any information about this online, so I'm just looking for a straight answer.

Comment: If it was just the factorial in the numerator, you probably could use multiplicativity of Legendre symbol. But with the $+1$, I see no way to proceed but to compute $n!+1\pmod p$...

Comment: @Aurel Unfortunately `n` will never be greater than or equal to `p` in my case.

Comment: Yes, I realised it and deleted the comment ;-)

Comment: It seems that some people want to close this question reasoning "I don't see a good answer and I don't think that a good answer exists". Which I cannot agree with.

Comment: Sorry, what is the trouble? THe Legendre symbol $(a/p)$ depends only on $a\mod p$, so you can really replace the numerator by $n!+1\mod p$. Is it the rest that is not achievable?